# Fixing openproject configuration broken by upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, openproject

I used apt to install a local version of openproject 9 on ubuntu xenial using apache2 and postgres. I had it working fine for several weeks, and then had the temerity to accept an offered package upgrade, which broke the configuration.

I have tried "openproject configure", which appeared to complete successfully but did not fix the problem. This is the error message:

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)
  /opt/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:585:in `validate_secret_key_base'
  /opt/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:432:in `secret_key_base'
  /opt/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:176:in `key_generator'
```

I am running passenger in an apache2 virtual server based very closely on the provided conf files. My only confusion with these is that these 'Include' *.conf files from /etc/openproject, but there are no files there to include.

I can see that an env var SECRET_KEY_BASE is defined in `/opt/openproject/.profile.d/ruby.sh` and if I insert command 'env' after reading profile.d in the /usr/bin/openproject shell file it does read the a setting for the secret key.

What has happened, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You set this secret_key with environment variable, but it require from you to set it on rails credentials:edit. Probably that env is redundant and the only proper place is the credentials in that case.
It's ok to save it on cridentials, as long as you have master.key safe. 
If you have generated master.key, then pass that secret_key credentials. You can run it by EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit

Comment: When I try the edit, I get an error about the database url: `sudo -H -uopenproject bin/rails credentials:edit` ... `(erb):1:in 'fetch': key not found: "DATABASE_URL" (KeyError)` although this doesn't happen from passenger. In addition, the 'additional commands' list in rails --help fails in the same way.